# The Real Operations Behind L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

When using L'Hopital's Rule we have 4 conditions to verify. One of them is that $ \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=c$ where c and a are both real numbers or infinity.

The issue with using L'Hopital's rule is that there are discontinuous derivatives, so when proving something involving L'Hopital's rule it seems to always be good to have $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f'(x) =k$ provided.

Is this due to limits working like this:

$ \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{\lim \limits_{x\to a} (f(x)-f(a)) }{\lim \limits_{x\to a} (g(x)-g(a))} = \frac{\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x)-\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(a)}{\lim \limits_{x\to a} g(x)-\lim \limits_{x\to a} g(a)}$

So that when you have the derivative of $f(x)$ (after differentiating the numerator of the example funciton) you can just substitute your assumed $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f'(x) =k$ for $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f'(a)$ ?

Comment: What's the actual question here? I don't recall the Hospital requiring the existence of $\lim f'(x)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It requires $ \lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=c$ to exist. So $f'(x)$ must but in proofs with L'Hopital's rule it seems that having the limit of $f'(x)$ as it approaches a makes proving it possible. I was just wondering if this was due to limit working the way as I hypothesized above. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: Look at $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2}$. The limit is obvious but we can still apply LHR to get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos x}{2x} = 0$ even though the limit of the numerator does not exist.

Comment: @RRL isn't that due to the squeeze/sandwich theorem though? And how would you apply the limit definition of derivative to this case? f(a) where a = infinity is undefined. So if you were to make a claim about the derivative of this function (in the limit form) being equal to the limit of the derivative function at infinity, you wouldn't right? You would need the limit of the derivative at infinity?

Answer (score 0):

L'hospital's rule works because of this:  If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x=a$ then by linear approximation:

$$f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$$

and

$$g(x) \approx g(a) + g'(a)(x-a).$$

Since we're assuming $f(a)=g(a) =0$ we have

$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \approx
\frac{f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)}{g(a) + g'(a)(x-a)} 
= \frac{0 + f'(a)(x-a)}{0 + g'(a)(x-a)}  = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}.$$